# What does "extension by approximation" mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, markov-chains, lp-spaces, markov-process

I'm reading *Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory* by Eisner *et al*. In multiple occasions, they use the combination "extension by approximation'' or alike. Specifically, the first part of their **Proposition 13.6** reads as follows.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be probability spaces and let $1\leq p \leq \infty$. Then the restriction mapping
> $\Phi_p:M(X;Y)\to M_p(X;Y)$ with $\Phi_p(S):=S|_{L^p}$ is a bijection.

In the above, $S:L^p(X)\to L^p(Y)$ is a Markov operator so that it satisfies $S \geq 0$, $S1 = 1$
and $\int_Y Sf = \int_X f$ for all $f \in L^p(X)$. $M_p(X;Y)$ is the set of all Markov operators from $L^p(X)$ to $L^p(Y)$ and $M(X;Y)=M_1(X;Y)$.

Then the proof of this part goes as follows.

> Each $S\in M_p(X;Y)$ satisfies $||Sf||_1=\int_Y |Sf|\leq \int_Y S|f|=\int_X |f|=||f||_1$ for all $f\in L^p (X)$. Hence, $S$ extends uniquely to a Markov operator on $L^1$ by approximation, and $\Phi_p$ is bijective.

I don't understand what exactly "$S$ extends uniquely to a Markov operator on $L^1$ by approximation" means and I'm hoping you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The space $L_p (X)$ is dense subspace of $L_1 (X)$ and $S$ is defined on $L_p (X).$ So by Hahn - Banach Theorem you can extend $S$ to an operator $S_1 $ on whole $L_1 (X)$ but since $L_p (X)$ is dense in $L_1 (X)$ the extension must be unique, since every $f\in L_1 (X) $ can be approximate by functions $f_n\in L_p (X) $ such $||f_n -f||_1 \to 0.$

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful.